# I have a CPT that have menu_order enabled, how can I make the menu_order values unique so it won't have duplicates

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a CPT named **homeslider**. I have **menu_order** page-attribute enabled, how can I make the menu_order values unique so it won't have duplicates when assigning values to it?

Comment: You may add validation before post is updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interfere with `save_post` action then change `menu_order` to `post_ID`:

```
add_action('save_post', function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    if ($post->menu_order === $post_id) {
        return $post_id;
    } else {
        global $wpdb;

        $q = "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET menu_order=%d WHERE ID=%d";

        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare($q, [$post_id, $post_id]) );

        return $post_id;
    }
}, 9, 3);
```